# Sample 5 times and sum, with replacement

Tags: r, for-loop, sum, resampling

I am trying to sample with replacement with a slight twist. I want to sample a list, vector, etc... 5 times and sum that. And replace the 5 sampled values, and do this 1000 times.

```
x<- 1:1000
samp <- matrix(NA, ncol = 1, nrow = 1000)
for(i in length(x)){
samp[i,] <- sum(sample(x,5,replace = TRUE))}
```

What I cant figure out is why this loop isnt working

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You missed `1:` in front of `length(x)` (i.e. from 1 to length of x by 1). Your code should be like this:

```
x<- 1:1000
samp <- matrix(NA, ncol = 1, nrow = 1000)
for(i in 1:length(x)){
  samp[i,] <- sum(sample(x,5,replace = TRUE))}
```

Which works great:

```
> str(samp)
 int [1:1000, 1] 2715 2312 3180 1364 2851 2429 2888 2381 2772 2317 ...
```

Also, `for-loops` have a bad reputation of being slow in R so you might want to consider other ways of looping like using the `C++` way with (for example) `replicate` like this:

Define the function:

```
myfunc <- function(x) {
  sum(sample(x,5,replace = TRUE))
}
```

And then use it like this:

```
x <- 1:1000
mymat <- matrix(replicate(1000, myfunc(x)), ncol=1)

> str(mymat)
 int [1:1000, 1] 2481 2236 2492 1759 1905 3243 2606 2624 3013 2309 ...
```

Comment: This works great! Also thanks for the function idea :)

Comment: Really glad I could be of help :)